# Creative Recon3D Fatal1ty no longer working on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, sound-card

When building my Digital Audio Workstation three years ago, I chose a Creative Recon3D Fatal1ty sound card. It's worked just fine until the past few months, during which time it has begun having problems.

I've researched the heck out of it over the past month, to little avail: Creative lists it as a legacy product, so there's no help from that quarter. I've updated firmware and drivers, reinstalled drivers, and kept it working for awhile.

The issues started to happen on a reboot after Windows Updates, which is what I suspect is the issue. I've read that there are problems (with workarounds) on Windows 10, but this machine is running the same Windows 7 x64 version it was originally built with, and nothing else has changed on the machine.

The symptoms are that the front panel lights no longer come on, and the system says that no sound device is installed. Device Manager now shows nothing where the Fatal1ty used to be listed.

Any input or a workaround would be greatly appreciated: this thing cost $400, and I'd hate to think that I'll never be able to trust Creative again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hardware fails, sounds like that happens, this isn't something a driver can solve.  Why is a legacy product still $400?

Answer (score 0):

The final answer to this question is that Creative SoundBlaster is no longer the dependable product it was in previous years. Never again will that company see one single dime of my hard-earned cash. I will hand-build a front panel which I'll use with a new ASUS DS-7. That is all.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)